# Vertically center image in footer/header

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, memoir

I have made a footer in `memoir` as shown below. The problem is that I would like to vertically center the image relative to the other text in the footer (the problem is identical in headers, I believe). How is this done?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Header and footer
\makepagestyle{myStyle}             % initialize style
\makeevenhead{myStyle}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{myStyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{myStyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myStyle}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image}}{exampleText}{Page \thepage{} of \thelastpage}
\pagestyle{myStyle}                 % activate style


\begin{document}

content

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\adjincludegraphics[valign=M,...]` from the `adjustbox` package.  The command `\adjincludegraphics` can also be used as a drop-in replacement for regular `\includegraphics` when omitting additional parameters like `valign`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

% Header and footer
\makepagestyle{myStyle}             % initialize style
\makeevenhead{myStyle}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{myStyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{myStyle}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myStyle}{\adjincludegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth,valign=M]{example-image}}{exampleText}{Page \thepage{} of \thelastpage}
\pagestyle{myStyle}                 % activate style


\begin{document}

content

\end{document}
```

[image]